# Mysqli Table Joins

Tags: php, mysql

I have a news table and want to link it to the members table to get the author information using Left Join, but I can't get the information to show from my php statement. Here is my php code:

Members Table: id, type, username, name, avatar

News Table: id, type, title, article, poster

```
<?php
CODE FOR PAGINATION
?>
<?php
if($usertype == "pub"){
    $get_articles_sql = "SELECT news.*, members.avatar, members.type AS membertype, members.name FROM news LEFT JOIN members ON members.id = news.poster LIMIT $offset, $post_limit";
}
else if($filter == "false"){
    $get_articles_sql = "SELECT news.*, members.avatar, members.type AS membertype, members.name FROM news LEFT JOIN members ON members.id = news.poster WHERE 3959 * acos( Cos( RADIANS(lat) ) * Cos( RADIANS('$yourlat') ) * Cos( RADIANS('$yourlon') - RADIANS(lon) ) + Sin( RADIANS(lat) ) * Sin( RADIANS('$yourlat'))) <= $yourradius ORDER BY news.date DESC LIMIT $offset, $post_limit";
}
else{
    $get_articles_sql = "SELECT news.*, members.avatar, members.type AS membertype, members.name FROM news LEFT JOIN members ON members.id = news.poster WHERE 3959 * acos( Cos( RADIANS(lat) ) * Cos( RADIANS('$yourlat') ) * Cos( RADIANS('$yourlon') - RADIANS(lon) ) + Sin( RADIANS(lat) ) * Sin( RADIANS('$yourlat'))) <= $yourradius AND type = '$filter' LIMIT $offset, $post_limit";
}
$get_articles_res = mysqli_query($con, $get_articles_sql);
if($get_articles_res){
    $num_articles = mysqli_num_rows($get_articles_res);
}else{
    $num_articles = "0";
}
?>
<?php
if($num_articles > 0){
while($article = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_articles_res)){
    $article_id = $article["id"];
    $article_type = $article["type"];
    $article_title = $article["title"];
    $article_article = $article["article"];
    $article_city = $article["city"];
    $article_town = $article["county"];
    $article_date = $article["date"];
    $article_avatar = $article["avatar"];
    $article_name = $article["name"];
    $article_membertype = $article["membertype"];

    $show_article .= "

        <div class=\"section\">
            <div class=\"sectionInner\">
                <div class=\"searchAvatar\"><img class=\"searchAvatarSize\" src=\"uploads/avatars/$article_avatar\"></div>
                <div class=\"searchInformationLeft\"><div class=\"searchInformationPrimary\">$article_title</div><div class=\"searchInformationSecondary\"><i>&quot;$article_article&quot;</i></div></div>
                <div class=\"searchInformationRight\"><div class=\"searchInformationPrimary\">By $article_name</div><div class=\"searchInformationSecondary\">$article_membertype, $article_city</div><div class=\"searchInformationThird\"><a href=\"event.php?id=$event_id&url=".urlencode($url)."\">View Details</a></div></div>
                <div class=\"clearLeft\"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=\"searchResultSplitter\"></div>

    ";
}
}else{...}
?>
```

I've tried this using just "SELECT * FROM new WHERE..." and it works fine so there must be something wrong in the join. Any ideas?

Comment: We'd really need to see a bit more - an echo, perhaps - to help with that. Also, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless

Comment: @Strawberry Why? Limit in this case is for pagination purposes

Comment: Put simply, rows in RDBMs tables have no natural order. You have to define one.

Comment: @Strawberry I don't want to order it by anything, I just want to limit all the results for pagination - Back to the question, can you see why this statement isn't working?

Comment: query seems fine, did you `echoed` the query in directly run in MySQL ?

Comment: @user2711490 Yeah, back to my original comment then

Comment: @Noor As far as I know everything is echoed ok as it works fine when I take out the Join - I've added more code

Comment: You're injecting variables into your query and hence you're making it open to SQL injection. Magically changing `mysql_` to `mysqli_` does not fix this. Use prepared statements and bind variables, or at *least* use [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: @h2ooooooo - I'm using real_escape for my form inputs but seeing as nothing in this script is coming from User Inputs I don't see how SQL injection is a problem?

Comment: The query looks fine as it stands. May be worth putting an or die(mysqli_error($con)); on the mysqli_query line. At least then if there is an error it will report it.

Comment: Why ppl do this all over: `$article_membertype = $article["membertype"];` why not simply **use** `$article["membertype"]`

Comment: @DanFromGermany Because I want to echo $article_membership in several places throughout the rest of the page

Comment: @user2711490 you could simply echo `$article["membertype"]` throughout the rest of the page. Sorry I did not want to advice you, I just interessted why copy all the variables

Comment: @DanFromGermany To be honest I never thought of doing it like that - When I was learning PHP from a book, that's the way is showed me and I guess I just always stuck to the same method ever since

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the 2nd and 3rd queries is that you are trying to use the columns **lat** and **lon** in the calculation, but you do not have columns called that in either the news table or the members table.

Comment: Thanks - There actually were 2 columns for Lon and Lat but htey were part of the problem - I should have been using `Cos( RADIANS(news.lat)` instead - Corrected it now but thanks again